# Combine legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot of multiple `geom_point` and a single `stat_function` in `ggplot2`. Is there a way to show a single legend?

```
df <- data.frame("x"=c(1:5), "a"=c(1,2,3,3,3), "b"=c(1,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.5))
df <- melt(df, "x")
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=variable, shape=variable)) +
  stat_function(aes(colour="log2(x)"), fun=log2)
```

[image]

I want to have a single legend with the blue line and the two colored shapes. I tried

```
scale_colour_discrete(name="legend", breaks=c("a", "b", "log2(x)")) +
scale_shape_discrete(name="legend", breaks=c("a", "b"))
```

but this does not work. Is there a way to do this automatically or by hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably an easier alternative is to use `override.aes` as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = variable, shape = variable), size = 3) +
  stat_function(aes(colour = "log2(x)"), fun = log2, size = 1.5) +
  guides(shape = FALSE,
         colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 17, NA),
                                                   linetype = c("blank", "blank", "solid"))))
```

which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Specify a `.` as the shape symbol for your curve and a blank line for your points:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=variable, shape=variable, linetype = variable), size = 3) +
  stat_function(aes(colour="log2(x)", shape = "log2(x)", linetype = "log2(x)"), fun=log2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = setNames(c(16, 17, 46), c("a", "b", "log2(x)"))) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = setNames(c(0, 0, 1), c("a", "b", "log2(x)")))
print(p)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I think the answer of @Jaap is the more "official" way.

Comment: Sure, if you can remember it, which I can't.

Comment: I recommend this option over the currently accepted answer. Overriding the guides carries a risk of human error, causing inaccurate guides that mislabel the values. With this answer, however, the guide will always be accurate, even if mistakes are made in the scale specification.