# Manually scale color, shape, and linetype of multiple geoms ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

A partial solution to my problem is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236495/combine-legend-in-ggplot2). I will show how that solution works and what features are still lacking to meet my needs.  For consistency, I use a sample data set that is similar to the one from the other thread:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), a = c(1,2,3,3,3), b = c(1,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.5))
df <- mutate(df, log2 = log2(x))
df <- df <- melt(df, c("x", "log2"))
```

An initial plot of the data (created by the following code) has the `shape` and `color` aesthetics in separate legends, which is undesirable:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, value, colour = variable, shape = variable), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x, log2, color = "log2(x)"), size = 1.5)
```

The solution proposes using `guides()` and `override.aes` to combine these into a single legend, which is certainly an improvement over the original plot:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, value, colour = variable, shape = variable), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x, log2, color = "log2(x)"), size = 1.5) +
  guides(shape = FALSE,
         colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 17, NA),
                                                   linetype = c("blank", "blank", "solid"))))
```

My issue is that I would like manual control of the `color` aesthetic in  both `geom_point` and `geom_line`.  For example, I want to make the triangles light grey, the circles dark grey, and the `log2(x)` line light blue. My understanding of how `guides()` works is very limited, so the best I have been able to do is the following:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, value, shape = variable), color = "gray40", size = 3, data = filter(df, variable == "a")) +
  geom_point(aes(x, value, shape = variable), color = "gray70", size = 3, data = filter(df, variable == "b")) +
  geom_line(aes(x, log2, shape = "log2(x)"), color = "cadetblue2", size = 1.5) +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("gray40", "gray70", "cadetblue2"),
                                                  shape = c(16, 17, NA),
                                                  linetype = c("blank", "blank", "solid"))))
```

This seems like an improper use of the `shape` aesthetic in `geom_line` (given the warning generated), however it is *almost* the result I want.  The problem now is that the legend icon for `log2(x)` is missing.  Ideally it should show a horizontal light blue line that matches the plot.  Does anyone know how to achieve this and/or could better explain how the `guides()` function is intended to be used?

I have also tried solutions using a combination of `scale_color_manual()`, `scale_linetype_manual()`, and `scale_shape_manual()` (all with the same `name` argument that way they should end up in a single legend).  The issue with this approach has been that all 3 geom layers have a `color` aesthetic, but only the first two have a `shape` aesthetic and only the last one has a `linetype` aesthetic.  So even if all of the `scale_xx_manual()` additions to `ggplot` are set up correctly, the legends are not combined into a single one.

I have been stuck on this for a long time, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just create a manual color scale and that will change the colors in both the plot and the guide. In general, you always want to favor using a scale over overriding guide values because it removes the risk of making mistakes in the guide which could cause your visualization to lie.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, value, colour = variable, shape = variable), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x, log2, color = "log2(x)"), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("a" = "gray40", "b" = "gray70", "log2(x)" = "cadetblue2")) +
  guides(shape = FALSE,
         colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 17, NA),
                                                   linetype = c("blank", "blank", "solid"))))
```

Edit:

Here's a version that also avoids doing the guide override on shape:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, value, colour = variable, shape = variable, linetype = variable), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x, log2, color = "log2(x)", linetype = "log2(x)", shape = "log2(x)"), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("a" = "gray40", "b" = "gray70", "log2(x)" = "cadetblue2")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("a" = 16, "b" = 17, "log2(x)" = NA)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("a" = "blank", "b" = "blank", "log2(x)" = "solid"))
```

`ggplot` will automatically combine legends when the name, labels, and direction are identical ([1](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/8778b48b37d8b7e41c0f4f213031fb47810e70aa/R/guide-legend.r#L231), [2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/8778b48b37d8b7e41c0f4f213031fb47810e70aa/R/guides-.r#L201)), so you just have to make sure "a", "b", and "log2(x)" all have mappings to each aesthetic in the same order. In this case, we accomplish this by adding unnecessary mappings to the layers and ignoring the warnings.

Comment: Great thank you! Could you explain the reasoning for chosing `shape = FALSE` as opposed to one of the other two aesthetics?

Comment: @AddisonKlinke In that version, it doesn't matter which of the two you set as false or you could set them both to the same value (i.e. `guide_legend(...)`) and you would get the same result (because they would be identical and would merge). Linetype doesn't need to be set because its not mapped to anything in the plot so it won't get a legend. Also check out my edit which has another solution that doesn't use `guides()` at all

Comment: I had a similar question as OP and your first solution worked for me very well (the second did not). But I notice that you have to be very specific on `shape = c(16, 17, NA)`. If you did `shape = c(15, 16, NA)`, you would get your legend to change but the shapes in the plot will not change. I used this same data for testing that (although I had multiple dataframes, one for lines and two different for different points.) I wonder is @W.Murphy can help some more, this is a post from long back, but any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Anirban_Mitra that's the risk with using override.aes, it changes the contents of the guide without respect to what's in the chart. For the second version, have you ensured each of your scales has identical name, labels, and direction properties? Or it's possible ggplot has changed since 2017 and option 2 no longer works

Comment: @W.Murphy option 2 works well for this particular dataframe, i.e. I can do `scale_shape_manual(values = c("a" = 15, "b" = 16, "log2(x)" = NA))`. Although it will throw up warning for using `linetype` in `geom_point` and `shape` in `geom_line`, it will not work if these arguments were removed. But unfortunately, option 2 does not work on the structure of data I have; likely because I have multiple dataframes for lines & points. I appreciate you took the time to reply.